# Texbox value in popup remains null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

I have a php page which contains this block of code:

```
echo '<div id="popup" style="display:none">';
echo '<form id="AddForm" name="AddForm" method="get">';
echo '<table><tr>';
echo '<td>Software Name: </td><td><input type="text" id="SoftwareName"/></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Software Type:</td><td><input type="text" id="SoftwareType"/></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>License Method:</td><td><input type="text" id="LicenseMethod"/></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><input type="button" value="Add" OnClick="opener.GetAddData();"></td><td></td>';
echo '</tr></table>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
```

Buttan that calls **CreatePopup()**:

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Add' OnClick='CreatePopup();'/>";
```

I am opening this div as a popup by using the following code:

```
function CreatePopup()
{   
       var w = null;
        w = window.open('index.php?List=SoftwareLicenseAllocations', 'test', 'height=125,width=300');
        w.document.write( $("#popup").html());
        w.document.close();
}
```

Code that gets the textbox values from the popup:

```
function GetAddData()
{   
    var SoftwareName = document.getElementById('SoftwareName').value;//.getElementById('SoftwareName').value;
    var SoftwareType = document.getElementById('SoftwareType').value;
    var LicenseMethod =document.getElementById('LicenseMethod').value;        

    alert(SoftwareName, SoftwareType, LicenseMethod);       

    AddNew(SoftwareName,SoftwareType,LicenseMethod);

}
```

Screenshot:

[image: POPUP]

Whenever I call GetAddData() and insert text in the popup box and click the button, the values remain null.

Why is this happening? How can I get the textbox values?

I am using Pear PHP and a modified version of OpenIT ( and old asset management CMS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly... Perhaps this?

**Change this line (just added window):**

```
echo '<tr><td><input type="button" value="Add" OnClick="opener.GetAddData(window);"></td><td></td>';
```

**And add a window parameter to the `GetAddData` function:**

```
function GetAddData(window)
{   
    var popupDoc = window.document;
    var SoftwareName = popupDoc.getElementById('SoftwareName').value;//.getElementById('SoftwareName').value;
    var SoftwareType = popupDoc.getElementById('SoftwareType').value;
    var LicenseMethod = popupDoc.getElementById('LicenseMethod').value;        

    alert(SoftwareName, SoftwareType, LicenseMethod);       

    AddNew(SoftwareName,SoftwareType,LicenseMethod);
}
```

When you call `opener.GetAddData` in your popup, the DOM methods are searching in the `opener` document, and not in the popup. You need to pass the popup's `window` object to the function, so that it knows it should look for the inputs in the popup's `document`.

Comment: That works, but it is only getting the first value (SoftwareName) and not all.

Answer (score 0):

I think your form is submitting by this code

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Add' OnClick='CreatePopup();'/>";
```

try converting your type 'submit' to 'button'

```
echo "<input type='button' value='Add' OnClick='CreatePopup();'/>";
```

Comment: I had previously tried that, still the same problem.